# HTML Support page through XML,XSLT,HTML, CSS, Bootstrap. .NET

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, xslt, adminlte

I am trying to generate a generic Support/Help page for all the applications in the company. Requirement as below:

- Each Application will have an XML page (which will have predefined structure) about application Support/installation/FAQ etc.
- Based on this xml page we need to create html page (though XSLT) and using some better bootstrap (AdminLTE etc) library (For better look and feel)
- Home Page will be generated from a different XML which will have link and path to the XML.

**Links.xml as below:**

```
<Links>
  <link>
    <url>Application 1</url>
    <FilePath>/Files/App1.xml</FilePath>
  </ link >
  <link>
    <url>Application 2</url>
    <FilePath>/Files/App2.xml</FilePath>
  </link >
  <link>
    <url>Application 3</url>
    <FilePath>/Files/App3.xml</FilePath>
  </link >
</Links>
```

**And then Application XML file as below: App.xml**

```
<Contents>
  <Header> Help Path for Application 1</Header>
  <Summary> This application is used to raise new requests to create User ID’s. It has workflow attached to it which can be used ?????. 
</Summary>
  <Support>
    <Email>abc@gmail.com </Email>
    <Phone> +1 82828 29282 2727 </Phone>
    <Text> Please contact ??? in department </Text>
  </Support>
  <FAQS>
    <FAQ>
      <QUESTION> For installation what I should Do</ QUESTION >
      <ANSWER> Click on this link. And download the installer. Please note that you need Admin rights for it. /ANSWER>
        <ANSWER> If you are on company network then it can be installed through My Portal </ANSWER>
      </FAQ>
      <FAQ>
        <QUESTION> Question 2</ QUESTION >
        <ANSWER> Answer 1 /ANSWER>
          <ANSWER> Answer 2 </ANSWER>
          <ANSWER> Answer 3 </ANSWER
</FAQ>
        </FAQS>
      </Contents>
```

And then finally we need output as below in HTML (Example only)

[image]

Idea is to keep it flexible so whenever a new application need to add it can be added by making an entry to Links.xml and by creating corresponding XML file.

1. I can use ASP.NET web forms or MVC for this.
2. Or Simple Static html pages. Although I preferred MVC

Any idea how I should pursue this? and some examples on this will be appreciable.

Cheers.

Comment: In my point of view XSLTs are extremely hard to maintain. They can grow in to 10s of 1000s of lines over the years. I cannot think of any benefit in creating xml and then converting them in to html using xslt. That's not the MVC way.

Comment: Benefit is that new application can be added without creating/changing new htmp/aspx pages. I think there will be only one XSLT file and multiple XML files And Max will be 50-60 applications.

Comment: You can achieve the same thing using pure MVC. You can maintain everything you need to create a UI in a database. That will be much easier than handling this using xslt. I am not even sure how you are planning to `post` from a xslt based view. You may be able to do that using jquery.

Comment: The company I work, does not allow new database creation, unless it can be justified. Reason because expensive to maintain. So I have been told to make it flexible (Application can be added/removed from page) without using database. I think MVC view allow to return and then render XSLT.

Comment: MVC views are html. In your case you need to transform your xml using XSLT to generate html. I cannot see how MVC can be used in this process.

Comment: I can see. I will post here once done!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have a solution, it is called ProjFlx, and open source project hosted on GitHub:  https://github.com/Xportability/ProjFlx

ProjFlx usage nearly matches your requirements to a T, with exception to your  structure , although this web framework is so flexible that you could easily incorporate that in yours.  Otherwise, the entire application navigation is driven from a common directory structure and common Xml document found within each folder.  The content in this Xml is written to the page.  Within this page Xml you will find sub-page-sections in  ..  structure.

ProjFlx is in use on several sites including:  meetscoresonline.com, riocrest.com, xportability.com, cloudformatter.com, and more.

An example says it all.  I've included a link to this Xml document from the website meetscoresonline.com/help

[Xml for this Page]
http://www2.meetscoresonline.com/Resources/projectFlx/Help/help.xml

[Xsl for this Page]
http://www2.meetscoresonline.com/Resources/projectFlx/Help/help.xml

[A more extreme Xslt example]
http://www2.meetscoresonline.com/Resources/projectFlx/Register/Register.xsl

ProjFlx content can be distributed to your CDN so you have complete separation of web content and your binaries.

ProjFlx is an open source project, along with its .Net src.

The ProjFlx code is written in C#.  The Projflx core exposes 3 tiers, TMPLT / SITE / PAGE.  Each have an INIT / MAIN / TERMINATE.  TMPLT MAIN calls SITE INIT then SITE MAIN then SITE TERMINATE and SITE MAIN calls PAGE INIT / PAGE MAIN / PAGE TERMINATE.  In your code, (typical) you overwrite each of the virtual SITE methods, and then per page request you write necessary business logic for the page.

ProjFlx is not MVC and ProjFlx is not Windows Forms, it is its own web framework utilizing C# .NET on the backend, Xml/Xslt to generate HTML with Twitter Bootstrap built in.  ProjFlx includes its own custom data layer with built in XmlWriter operations for generating "good" Xml (not the Xml you get from and ADO.Net recordset).  This data class will even "explode json" to Xml from a field in your DB.  Suppose you have some field whose contents is:

```
{ "ProjFlx": { "Version":"1.0", "License":"Open" }}
```

Is exploded in your resulting Xml as:

```
<ProjFlx>
   <Version>1.0</Version>
   <License>Open</License>
</ProjFlx>
```

I hope you take a look!

Comment: Cool. I will have a look into it. Is there any documentation available on this?

Comment: @user2739418 some documentation but nowhere where it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that is uses purely XSLT.

**The home page will be ...**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>ACME Corporation Support Page</title>
  <link href="support.css" rel=stylesheet type="text/css"> 
  <!-- Use support.css to style the page, as you please. --> 

  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/Saxonce/Saxonce.nocache.js"></script> 
  <script type="application/xslt+xml" language="xslt2.0" src="support.xsl" data-source="Links.xml"></script>  

<style>
span.pseudo-a { /* Mimic an 'a' element. */
     cursor:pointer;
     color:blue;
     text-decoration:underline;
}
span.pseudo-a:hover {
    color: #444444;    
</style>

</head>

<body>
<form>
  <h3>ACME Corporation - Our Products</h3> 
</form>


<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="left-pane">
      </td>
      <td id="right-pane">Click an application link on the left-hand panel for more information.
      </td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

**The links data file will look like this ...** (relative url `Links.xml`)

```
<Links>
  <link>
    <url>Application 1</url>
    <FilePath>app-meta/App1.xml</FilePath>
  </link>
  <link>
    <url>Application 2</url>
    <FilePath>app-meta/App2.xml</FilePath>
  </link >
  <link>
    <url>Application 3</url>
    <FilePath>app-meta/App3.xml</FilePath>
  </link >
</Links>
```

***... and the application specific files will look like this...** (relative url like `app-meta/App1.xml` etc.)

```
<Contents>
    <Header> Help Path for Application 1</Header>
    <Summary> This application is used to raise new requests to create User ID&apos;s. It has workflow attached to it which can be used. 
      </Summary>
    <Support>
        <Email>abc@gmail.com </Email>
        <Phone> +1 82828 29282 2727 </Phone>
        <Text> Please contact George in department </Text>
    </Support>
    <FAQS>
        <FAQ>
            <QUESTION> For installation what I should Do</QUESTION>
            <ANSWER> Click on this link. And download the installer. Please note that you need Admin rights for it. </ANSWER>
            <ANSWER> If you are on company network then it can be installed through My Portal </ANSWER>
        </FAQ>
        <FAQ>
            <QUESTION> Question 2</QUESTION>
            <ANSWER> Answer 1 </ANSWER>
            <ANSWER> Answer 2 </ANSWER>
            <ANSWER> Answer 3 </ANSWER>
        </FAQ>
    </FAQS>
</Contents>
```

**This XSLT 2.0 stylesheet will style your xml data as required.** (relative url `support.xsl`)

```
<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ixsl="http://saxonica.com/ns/interactiveXSLT"
    xmlns:prop="http://saxonica.com/ns/html-property"
    xmlns:style="http://saxonica.com/ns/html-style-property"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs prop"
    extension-element-prefixes="ixsl"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="*" mode="#all" />

<xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:result-document href="#left-pane" method="ixsl:replace-content">
    Application List
    <ul>  
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Links/link" mode="left-pane" />   
    </ul>    
  </xsl:result-document>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="link" mode="left-pane">
  <li>
      <span FilePath="{FilePath}" class="pseudo-a">
        <xsl:value-of select="url"/>
      </span>
  </li>      
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="span[@FilePath]" mode="ixsl:onclick">
    <xsl:result-document href="#right-pane" method="ixsl:replace-content">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@FilePath)" mode="right-pane" />
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Contents" mode="right-pane">
  <h3><xsl:value-of select="Header"/></h3>
    <p><xsl:value-of select="Summary"/></p>
  <h4>For Support</h4>
    <p>Email: <xsl:value-of select="Support/Email" /></p>
    <p>Phone: <xsl:value-of select="Support/Phone" /></p>
    <p><xsl:value-of select="Support/Text" /></p>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="FAQS" mode="#current" />    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FAQS" mode="right-pane">
  <h4>FAQS</h4>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="FAQ/(QUESTION | ANSWER)" mode="#current" />    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="QUESTION" mode="right-pane">
    <h5><xsl:value-of select="." /></h5>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ANSWER" mode="right-pane">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

---

### Notes

1. To use XSLT 2.0, you will need to download the [Saxon CE javascript library](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml).
2. I haven't put any effort into nice commercial grade css styling. You can do that.
3. A pure XSLT solution will be orders of magnitude superior to any alternative solution involving ASP.NET or PHP or any other heavy-weight rubbish like that. The amount of code is microscopic. It will be simpler and cheaper to maintain.